# Help! Why is my pepper plant experiencing dogs vomit slime mold?

Tags: plant-care, peppers, mold

[image]

I have a potted pepper and tomato plant (I know I need to move one out for more space) but yesterday I walked out and my pepper plant was having its leaves just fall off and my tomato plants almost all lower half leaves were yellow. I walked out the next morning to see the slime. Is this the reason for my plants badly reacting? Also what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The slime mould won't be causing your plants ill health - what will be a cause is being kept too wet, or having poor or no drainage from the pot. Slime moulds appear in wet conditions; I've never seen it occur on potting soil before, but perhaps you used something else to pot your plants.

Best to separate the plants now and put them in pots with drainage holes in the bottom, using fresh potting soil.